# Using time-stamp to retrieve the date and time separately. (mysql)

Tags: mysql, date, time, timestamp

Is timestamp in mysql able to retrieve the date and time separately?

Answer (score 1):

You can use DATE and TIME functions

```
select DATE(now()), TIME(now())
```

Comment: can you explain further more on how to use this? cos i need to use sql query to collect the data from the timestamp and den split into date and time. @Benos

Comment: select DATE(yourcolumnName), TIME(yourcolumnName)

Answer (score 0):

try `date_format` function on timestamp field , and you can retrieve date/time both

```
date_format(NOW(),'%d-%b-%Y') == Date

date_format(NOW(),'%T') == Time
```

Comment: may i know how to do so? i have to do it something like this 
"
DATE_FORMAT(NOW(),'%b %d %Y %h:%i %p')
DATE_FORMAT(NOW(),'%m-%d-%Y')
DATE_FORMAT(NOW(),'%d %b %y')
DATE_FORMAT(NOW(),'%d %b %Y %T:%f')
" ? @Satya

Comment: so you meant that using select date_format(now(),'%d-%b-%y') from table ? @Satya haha

Comment: i need to retrieve the current time as well as the past. other than date_format(now()) for the current time. how do i get data from the past ? @Satya

Comment: replace now with the value in your column